# Automatically encrypt varchar MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I have a table in mysql that has 5 fields. They are arranged like this:

```
id | name | email | username | password
```

What I want to do, is automatically hash the password when a value is inserted without having to call the md5 function.

So this is the query I tried using to get that affect:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
password md5(VARCHAR(255)) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Can I do something like this or will I have to call md5() whenever there is an `INSERT INTO` statement?

I know md5 is not as secure as others, etc, etc. No need to suggest other encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a trigger. For example:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER t BEFORE INSERT ON users
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.password = MD5(NEW.password);

mysql> INSERT INTO users (username, email, name, password) 
    VALUES ('user1', 'user1@example.com', 'user1', 'xyzzy');

mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+----+-------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | name  | email             | username | password                         |
+----+-------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | user1 | user1@example.com | user1    | 1271ed5ef305aadabc605b1609e24c52 |
+----+-------+-------------------+----------+----------------------------------+
```

You should also create a similar trigger `BEFORE UPDATE`.

This also creates a situation where it's legitimate to use a long varchar data type for the password column, even though the MD5 hash is by definition only 32 characters. If we were to restrict the varchar to 32 characters, then no one could create a password longer than 32 characters, because the length check is done before the trigger modifies the value.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO users (username, email, name, password) 
    VALUES ('user1', 'user1@example.com', 'user1', 'xyzzjfdkfjdsljfdskfjdslfjdsklfjfjdklfjdslkfjdslfjsdlky');
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'password' at row 1
```

By the way, MD5 is usually considered to be too weak to use as a password hashing function. Use SHA2 instead.

And it's also a good idea to concatenate the password with a random salt before hashing it. See [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you're attempting. Default values must be constants except in the case of time stamps. There are no other functions that can be applied via DDL.

You could hash the password in the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('someone', MD5('password'))
```

The `MD5()` function always returns a 32 character hex string, so no need for 255 characters.

Comment: Okay so this confirms what I expected. So I should set the password field to be varchar(32) instead?

Comment: @SlashTag, the size doesn't vary, so use `CHAR(32)`, and set the character set for the column to `ascii` (or `latin1`) so it's only one byte per character.